# Using lodash pad to format the very first number of an for loop based on a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I've created a console.log calendar through node js by the use of the moment framework. My problem is applying a pad specifically on the first day of the month so that it matches it's day. E.g. if they first day is Thursday, I would want the first day(1) to start on Thursday then break line after Saturday. Finally, it would break off and continue the loop to break line after every 7 days.

As of now, my Calendar does start from the first day and breaks correctly, but the first day(1) is always on Sunday due to my lack of understanding on how to pad the first number. Another thing to note is my calendar only goes to 7 right now but that's because I know how to do correct padding/line breaks after the first line.

```
let days = moment.weekdays().join(' ');
// Array of months
let theMonths = moment.monthsShort();

// Creation of each month
for (i = 0; i < theMonths.length; i++) {
  // Assigns each month to a variable to call moment functions
  var eachMonth = moment().month(theMonths[i]);
  // Creates calendar for each month
  console.log("-------" + theMonths[i] + "------");
  console.log(days);
  console.log(monthDays(eachMonth))
}

// this function handles creating all days of each month
function monthDays(month) {

  let display = '';
  for (x = 1; x <= month.daysInMonth(); x++) {
    if (x <= 7) {
      var holder = moment.weekdays().length;
      // subtracting the length of the week from the starting day of each month
      var firstLine = holder - month.weekday();
      // will break line based on first day
      if (x == firstLine) {
        display += "   " + x + "\n";
      } else {
        // padding for each number after(if neccesary) line break
        display += _.pad(x + " ", 8);

      }
    }
  }
  console.log(display)
}
```

Expected Results:

```
    Oct has: 31 days the first day is: 2
    -------Oct------
    Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
                      1       2       3       4       5
       6       7      etc.
```

Actual Results:

```
    Oct has: 31 days the first day is: 2
    -------Oct------
    Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
       1       2       3       4       5
       6       7       etc.
```

Comment: what's up with your indentation and closing brackets? This code wouldn't run.

Comment: yeah srry there's a few extra brackets within the function because I wasn't trying to copy code that's irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @AuronKelmud are you using JS in the browser or Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding in another way, here is an example and documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

```
String.prototype.padStart();
String.prototype.padEnd();
```

The `padStart()` method pads the current string with another string (multiple times, if needed) until the resulting string reaches the given length. The padding is applied from the start (left) of the current string, there is also `padEnd()`.

If we know that the longest string contains 7 letters for example, we could assume that a padding of 10 will keep things in line.

```js
// 'abc'.padStart(10);         // "       abc"
// 'abc'.padStart(10, "foo");  // "foofoofabc"

function output() {
    console.log('Expected Results:');
    console.log('Day has:', '# days from the first day is: #');
    console.log(
        ' Day'.padStart(0),
        'Day'.padStart(7),
        'Day'.padStart(7),
        'Day'.padStart(7),
        '\n',
        '#'.padStart(0),
        '#'.padStart(7),
        '#'.padStart(7),
        '#'.padStart(7),
        '\n',
        'Day'.padStart(0),
        'Day'.padStart(7),
        'Day'.padStart(7),
        'Day'.padStart(7),
        '\n',
        '#'.padStart(0),
        '#'.padStart(7),
        '#'.padStart(7),
        '#'.padStart(7),
    );
}

output();
```

Then if you are using Node.JS you could use `padStart()` and `padEnd()` in combination with the width of the terminal.

```
console.log('Size' + process.stdout.columns + 'x' + process.stdout.rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- You assume that `month.weekday();` gets the week day of the *first* day of the month, but you when you just create a moment for the month, the *current* day and time are retained in that moment, so you need to apply `.startOf("month")`
- You `console.log` the return value of the function call, but the function does not return anything; instead it outputs something itself.
- You currently break out of the loop at day number 7. Surely you want to output the other days of the month as well ;-)
- You use global variables for the loop variables. Make sure to declare them with local scope

Here is how your code could be adapted. Comments indicate where changes were made:

```js
const days = moment.weekdays().join(' ');
const theMonths = moment.monthsShort();
/// Don't use a global variable -- declare i:
for (let i = 0; i < theMonths.length; i++) {
    const eachMonth = moment().month(theMonths[i]).startOf("month"); /// <--- get first day
    console.log("-------" + theMonths[i] + "------");
    console.log(days);
    console.log(monthDays(eachMonth));
}

function monthDays(month) {
    const shift = month.weekday(); // Get shift of "1"
    const holder = moment.weekdays().length;
    let display = ' '.repeat(8 * shift); // Create indentation for "1"
    for (let x = 1; x <= month.daysInMonth(); x++) {
        const firstLine = x > 1 && (x-1+shift) % holder == 0; // <-- the magic!
        if (firstLine) display += "\n";
        display += _.pad(x + " ", 8);
    }
    return display; // <--- return
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks alot for this answer, clears alot of things up for me